# C# SCardControl return code 1

Tags: c#, .net, pcsc, winscard

This is my first attempt in using a card reader in C#, or basically anywhere.

I use `ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 0` reader in Windows 7 64bit.

My first problem occurs when I tried to connect to the reader using

```
ModWinsCard.SCardConnect(hContext, cbReader.SelectedItem.ToString(), ModWinsCard.SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT, 0, ref hCard, ref Protocol);
```

It returns error code 6, but I googled and solved it by changing project's platform from `Any CPU` to `X86`.

Right after that I bumped to another issue, this time in controlling the reader.

I tried with :

```
_sentBuffer = new byte[]
    {
         0xFF,
         0x00,
         0x48,
         0x00,
         0x00
    };
_receivedBuffer = new byte[10];

_receivedBuffer[0] = 0;

_returnCode = ModWinsCard.SCardControl(_hCard, _dwControlCode, ref _sentBuffer[0], _sentBuffer.Length, ref _receivedBuffer[0], _receivedBuffer.Length, ref bytesReturned);
```

The returned code is `1`, which is weird because I can't found it in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#smart_card_return_values).

Really need a hand in this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow have it solved by downloading the latest driver from the provider's website, with uninstalling the driver that is included in the driver CD.

Still wonder what does return 1 means though..

Answer (score 4):

Doing some research myself about working with `SCardControl` and found I was getting the same return value of `1`.

I found a list of Error Codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374738(v=vs.85).aspx#smart_card_return_values) which then states the below.

"**Note**  Some return values may have the same value as existing Windows return values that signify a similar condition. For information about error codes not listed here, see [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)."

And that documentation states that the error code value `1` is `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`

I know this question is old but hopefully it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Funny how I missed that note before.. So basically the error said that I was using the wrong function? A deprecated one perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure just yet, still working through other issues I'm facing working with the PC/SC Security Pin APIs. I'll let you know if i find anything further.

Comment: As you can see from my comment on my own answer below, I got the ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION due to the wrong ControlCode I passed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I have the same problem on Windows 10 (x64), except I'm using VB6.

I have a lot working through using `SCardTransmit` etc, I can controle/read/write if there's a card on it. But I want to control the reader (ACR112U) without a card (turn off autodetection/beep) and that's only possible using `SCardControl` (as far as I know), cause when I connect with Directmode and then call our SetBuzzerCardDetection to turn it off, I get a `ERROR_BAD_COMMAND`, but when shared and a card it works.

Even the example from ACS themselves with `IOCTL_GET_VERSIONS` gives me return value `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`

```
  Dim vcVersion       As VERSION_CONTROL
  Dim lReturnedLength As Long

  m_lResult = SCardControl(m_hCard, _
                           IOCTL_GET_VERSIONS, _
                           0, 0, _
                           vcVersion, 20, _
                           lReturnedLength)
  If m_lResult <> SCARD_S_SUCCESS Then
```

I'm using the following

```
Declare Function SCardControl Lib "WinScard.dll" ( ByVal hCard As Long, ByVal dwControlCode As Long, ByRef lpInBuffer As Any, ByVal lSizeofBuffer As Long, ByRef lpReceiveBuffer As Any, ByVal lpReceiveBufferSize As Long, ByRef lpBytesReturned As Long) As Long

Const IOCTL_CCID_ESCAPE         As Long = (&H42000000 + 3500)

'hCard is a valid handle returned by SCardConnect
'lReturn = SCardConnect(hContext, sReader, eShareMode, ePreferredProtocol, hCard, eActiveProtocol)
'With card on reader:    eShareMode = SCARD_SHARE_SHARED, ePrefferedProtocol = SCARD_PROTOCOL_Tx
'Without card on reader: eShareMode = SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT, ePrefferedProtocol = SCARD_PROTOCOL_UNDEFINED

Dim abIn()          As Byte
Dim abOut()         As Byte
Dim lInLength       As Long
Dim lOutLength      As Long
Dim lReturn         As Long
Dim lReturnedLength As Long
  
'Command for turning off Buzzer output during card detection
lInLength = 5
ReDim abIn(lInLength - 1)  
abIn(0) = &HFF
abIn(1) = &H0
abIn(2) = &H52
abIn(3) = &H0
abIn(4) = &H0

lOutLength = 256
ReDim abOut(lOutLength - 1)

lReturn = SCardControlAny(hCard, _
                          IOCTL_CCID_ESCAPE, _
                          abIn(0), lInLength, _
                          abOut(0), lOutLength, _
                          lReturnedLength)
'with card on reader:    lReturn = ERROR_BAD_COMMAND
'without card on reader: lReturn = ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION
```

Mind you for using Escape I also added the `ControlEscapeEnable` to the registry (just for the sake of it I added it in several places)
First I did everything without loading a special driver (other than what Windows 10 itself already got), but due to Samuel Adam's remark I loaded the latest from ACS website but it didn't make a difference.
It's really driving me crazy, just like it's also driving me crazy that WebUSB doesn't allow it anymore so I would have been able to use a webbased version.

Comment: I've found the problem, after reading the API documentation of the ACR1252U which does have an example of the SCardControl in it.
I got the 'ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION' due to the incorrect definition of 'IOCTL_CCID_ESCAPE' which should actually be '&H310000+(3500*4)' and not as Microsoft stated '&H42000000 + 3500'.
It was just as simple as that, so now I can control the reader without a card (you do need to use SCardConnect with Direct for it to work).